# parse cloud http rerquest

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

i am working on parse server with AWS , i am using microsoft face API  'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/' for detenct and identify faces , as you know the are no any option to debug the parse cloud code and the only option is to use the tool from github  "parse-cloud-debugger"
when i test the code there for the Parse.Cloud.httpRequest() all works fine and i get good response but after that when i put he same code to the real parse-server on AWS when i make the httpRequest in some reason i get (response.text) not as JSON object but as char array , that means i get array of thousands chars.

```
function detectFace(imgUrl){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var url ='https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/?   returnFaceId=true&returnFaceLandmarks=true';
        console.log(url);
        Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method:CONSTANTS.METHOD_POST,
            url:url,
            headers:{
                'Content-Type': CONSTANTS.CONTENT_TYPE_APP_JSON,
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': CONSTANTS.MICROSOFT_FACE_API_KEY
            },
            json:{
                'processData':false,
                'url':imgUrl
            }
        }).then(function(httpResult){
            resolve(httpResult);
        }).catch(function(e){
            reject(e);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Please reformat the question

Comment: can you explain how to paste the code correctly please?

Comment: ohh isee now thanks

Comment: Maybe you get an error with this code because of the `url`. There is Whitespace in the definition.

Comment: there are no whitespaces its just because i pasted it bad here , and the response is correct but as char array thats the only problem

Comment: this is the httpResult.text :[{"faceId":"XXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-04a743cf0f36","faceRectangle":..........{"x":1124.5,"y":1695.3},"eyebrowLeftOuter":{"x":1023.9,"y":1681.4},"underLipBottom":{"x":1020.6,"y":1720.8}}}] but all this is as char array i just made loop to create string from it